# Zoom google map on click

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to zoom a [google map](http://www.fabiotoscano.it/alfatours/index.php/viaggi-last-minute/10-india) on click event.. but i'll display a gray box

What can i do?

```
$(".zoomappa").click(function() {
          $('.zoomappa').hide();      
          $('.bt-googlemaps').animate({width:'710px'}, 500);
          $('.bt-googlemaps').animate({height:'640px'}, 500);
           $(window).trigger('resize');
          $('.nozoomappa').show();
         
     });
```

Comment: by zooming do you mean make the div bigger on screen?

Answer (score 0):

You should call map resize event after you change the div's dimensions.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Since your map variable (default.js, line 208) is set as private you cannot just add this line to the click function, so you'll have to work this one around yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
About line 208 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(configs.cavas_id), mapOptions);
what i have to do? 

Thank you

Comment: (bad practice) you can add something like global_map = map; in line 209, and call google.maps.event.trigger(global_map, 'resize'); in your click function. It will work, but that's not a good way and you should figure the best way that fits your coding style and structure.

Comment: var global_map = map; line 209 default.js and google.maps.event.trigger(global_map, 'resize'); in click function but not work..

Comment: Don't use "var" declaration, simply declare it. And please read around to see why it's bad a habit.

Comment: [LINE 208] var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(configs.cavas_id), mapOptions);
[LINE 209] global_map = map; and click function: $(".zoomappa").click(function() {
          $('.zoomappa').hide();  
          $('.bt-googlemaps').animate({width:'710px'}, 500);
          $('.bt-googlemaps').animate({height:'640px'}, 500);
    google.maps.event.trigger(global_map, 'resize');
          $('.nozoomappa').show();    
     }); but not work..